# Find (if there exists) a graph $G$ such that $X'(G)=5$ and $X(G)=6$. If there is no such a graph then explain why.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Find (if there exists) a graph $G$ such that $X'(G)=5$ and $X(G)=6$. If there is no such a graph then explain why.

So we know the following things

$[1]$ $X(G) \leq \Delta(G)+1$ or $X(G) \leq \Delta(G)$ if graph is connected and is neither a complete graph nor an odd cycle

$[2]$ $\Delta(G) \leq X'(G) \leq \Delta(G)+1$

So knowing the mentioned above properties we can state that there should exist such a graph and it should have $\Delta(G) = 5$ and it should be connected and complete or connected and an odd cycle, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, what you've argued is that *if* such a graph exists, it would need to have $\Delta(G)=5$, and *if* it's connected, it would have to be an odd cycle or a complete graph. (Given a connected example, we could always make a nonconnected example by, say, throwing in some extra isolated vertices.) On its own this doesn't tell you that such a graph *does* exist, but it suggest that there are only a few candidates that you need to look at -- and one of the obvious candidates does in fact turn out to work.

Comment: Right, so how should I now try to find one? Trial and error method?

Comment: @JamesSmith you've already narrowed down your search quite a bit: if you're looking for a connected example (and you might as well, since if there is an example, there's a connected one), you only need to look at complete graphs and odd cycles. Combined with the max degree restriction, what graphs are left to check?

Comment: We should consider $K_6$ for sure, but I can't think of any graph that has $\Delta(G)=5$ and is an odd cycle graph.

Comment: @JamesSmith Right, an odd cycle is $2$-regular, so the max degree restriction means we don't actually have to look at any odd cycles. You should be a little careful about double-checking what the max degree of $K_5$ is, though (try drawing it out, or drawing out $K_3$ which by the same reasoning "should" have max degree $3$, and you might notice the problem).

Comment: I have mistyped $K_5$. Of course it should be $K_6$. So the only thing that is left is to confirm that for $K_6$ $X(G)=6$ and $X'(G)=5$ by trying to color it?

Comment: @JamesSmith Confirming that $\chi(K_6) = 6$ would need an argument for why you need at least 6 colors, as well as a proper $6$-coloring (both of which should be easy); confirming that $\chi'(K_6) = 5$ would require a proper $5$-edge-coloring, which may take a little bit of work (the max degree immediately tells you that you can't do better than $5$ colors).